# javascript RegEx checking for any letters in string (needs to ignore other glyphs though - so not just 0-9)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to test a string that will potentially have numbers, letters, dashes, forward slashes and other glyphs in it. Only numbers, dashes and forward slashes should be allowed.
Tried a couple times but I keep getting the regex syntax wrong.

Basically:

```
var str = '03/02/2013'; //03-02-2013 is also acceptable 

if(str has letters in it){
  console.log('incorrect formatting');
}else{
  //string is made up of only numbers, dashes or forward slashes
  console.log('okay');
}
```

Comment: Can we see the syntax or the source of the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that your string *"is made up of only numbers, dashes or forward slashes"*, then you may use this one :

```
var isOK = /^[\d\-\/]*$/.test(str)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for str = '36/a/sss-3-6-'; Thinks it's an acceptable value.

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot Test it in your console : `/^[\d\-\/]*$/.test('36/a/sss-3-6-')` gives `false`. Should it give `true` ? Then please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a date format ? You could try

```
var str="10/12/2012"; 
var n=/^[0-9]{2}[\/-][0-9]{2}[\/-][0-9]{4}$/.test(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if the string only contains numbers, dashes and forward slashes, this should do the trick:

```
var EXP = /^[\d-\/]+$/;
```

This would match a string og any length with any number of any of the allowed characters. If you explicity want to make sure that the string conforms to a date format where both dashes and forward slashes:

```
var EXP = /^\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,4}$/;
```

This would match a date format that allows one or two digits for day and month and 2-4 digits for year, separated by dashes or forward slashes.